# Did the Colonials do any kind of spatial exploration?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004, battlestar-galactica-1978

In the BSG universe, before the Cylon attack and destroy the Colonial civilization, did the Colonial engaged in any kind of space exploration?

Whether by sending probes or ships to nearby systems or other parts of the galaxy, to look for resources, study interesting spatial phenomenon or just look for more places to establish new colonies and outposts.

I've seen only the new series, but I'm interested in the answer for both the original and reimagined.

Answer (score 10):

Important distinction: Original 1978 Battlestar Galactica? or Reimagined Ron Moore 2004 series?

In the original series, in the pilot episode, Apollo is on patrol with his brother Zac, and they exchange a conversation prior to encountering the cylon tankers where they discuss what they want to do after the armistice is signed. Apollo expresses a desire to return to deep star exploration. Based upon this conversation - manned probes over great distance seem likely.

Also in the living Legend, Adama states that there was no conflict with the Cylons until the colonists intervened in a conflict between the cylons and a third race (the cylons were not human creations in the original series) so they explored enough to encounter other civilizations.

Comment: Actually, both. ^^ I added this to my question.